# Is there a way to change the look of the expand / collapse boxes and lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to change how the Expand / Collapse boxes and lines look in Notepad++.

For example currently when you place your cursor within a xml or html tag, Notepad++ will turn the expand/collapse box and the lines connecting them to a thin red line.

If possible I would like to achieve some of the following....

1. Thicken up this red line and make it very bold so it stands out.
2. Maybe an option to change what the expand/collapse boxes look like (not that important)
3. Way to have Notepad++ highlight the background of the entire tag selected with a user definable color.  This would really help even more to make tags stand out.

If anyone has anything information they can share on the subject it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> `Style Configurator` -> `Global STyles`

As style, select Fold active.

Here you can change the line color, which is basically all you can do.

Additionally, you can change `Fold` itself, make it a lot brighter, which will cause the current Fold to stand out.

Also `Fold margin` changes the color of the "grey shaded border"

Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with these settings again earlier today and I was able to come up with decent settings, which I will share if anyone should ever search for this someday.  The best settings I found were:

- Turn the color of the fold margin to white
- Turn the color of the unselected vertical lines to very light grey
- Turn the background of the fold icons to a dark grey
- Keep the color of the select vertical lines red

This way when you select a tag the red vertical lines stand out.

Comment: as a friendly FYI: This site's structure is Questions and Answers, not the typical forum-style. Anything that is not an answer goes in the "comments" section, such as the text you are now reading. There is a comment section for every question and answer. For example, the words you wrote in response to LPChip should be written as a comment to his answer. This keeps important information easy to find and read. Answering your own question with new information is always encouraged, kudos. Enjoy your stay at super user!